# SQL Database not working with ASP.NET web form

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio, webforms

I am designing a web form on Visual Studio 2010 using ASP.NET framework. I am using SQL Database to connect my web form to the server, but there are some errors which I can't resolve?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to run a web form that connects to the database which when data entered into the form, stores the information into the server for the user to login later

The following is the code for the web form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=@"C:\Users\Kapalmeet Singh\Desktop\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 values('"+TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"','"+TextBox3.Text+"','"+TextBox4.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

    }
}
```

And here's the code for the web form

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                User Name</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        style="margin-left: 192px" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted those errors. And on a side note, look into sql injection and how to prevent it. Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: You are not using MySQL, you appear to be using SQL Server Express. Please tag your question correctly so a) it doesn't waste anyone's time and b) your question gets see by the right people with the right skills and interests. Please the the time to read the tag definitions before you add them, and make sure you use the right ones. Thanks.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. Not to mention plain old non-malicious apostrophes. What happens when someone named "O'Brien" wants to use this form? And don't get me starting on the problems storing plain-text passwords.

Comment: It's a project from my class, to develop a simple and straightforward website with SQL, I just want it to work and show it off to the faculty members, that's it. By the way, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your creating a registration it would be like this. Change the names for these the way they are called in your database and for the other ones to. (@FirstName, @Surname, @Password, @Username,)

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YOUR_CONNECION_STRING_HERE"].ConnectionString);

                conn.Open();


                string insertQuery = "insert into Table1(FirstName, Surname, Username, Password) " +
                    "values(@FirstName, @Surname, @Password, @Username,)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);


                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Textbox1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", Textbox2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Textbox3.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Textbox4.Text);

                //This actually executes the query with the given values above.
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();


                conn.Close();

                Response.Redirect("Name_Of_Any_Page_Thats_On_Your_Site.aspx");

                Response.Write("there was a problem with your registration");

            }
            catch (Exception problem)
            {
                //throw Exception ;
                Response.Write("Error Message: " + problem.ToString());
                throw;

            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: A fat tick would also be nice.